# $|a-b| \geq | |a| - |b| | \Longleftrightarrow |a-b| \geq |a| - |b| $?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Does the following always hold?

$|a-b| \geq | |a| - |b| | \Longleftrightarrow  |a-b| \geq  |a| - |b| $

Certainly, the second inequality implies the first, but the converse isn't so clear to me.

If it does hold, then why do we define the 'reverse triangle inequality' as the first inequality in the above?

Comment: The right implication is blatantly obvious whereas the left implication is obtained by symmetry (just switch position of a and b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both inequalities are always true, hence the bi-conditional is valid.

Explicitly,
$$|a| = |(a-b) + b| \le |a-b| + |b|$$
hence $|a-b| \ge |a|-|b|$.

Thus, the RHS is always true.

Similarly,
$$|b| = |(b-a) + a| \le |b-a| + |a| = |a-b| + |a|$$
hence $|a-b| \ge |b|-|a|$.

Since we have both
$$|a-b| \ge |a|-|b|$$
$$|a-b| \ge |b|-|a|$$
it follows that $|a-b| \ge ||a|- |b||$.

Thus, the LHS is always true.

Comment: But why then don't we use the simpler form as the definition of the backwards inequality?

Comment: @Stephen: I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Sure.  The triangle inequality  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) have at least two forms.  One is $ \ $ $|a+b|=<|a|+|b|$ $ \ $  and the other is the *first* inequality I gave in my question.  Why is the second form of the triangle inequality not given as the second inequality in my above post?  Why the additional complication produced by the surrounding  |     | ?

Comment: Since they're logically equivalent, it doesn't matter, but the LHS is "formally" stronger, in the sense that it's picking the nonnegative value, rather than just one of the two possible values.

Comment: You are proving triangular inequality the OP is asking only for the equivalence which is obvious by symmetry. This is not really the answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

The if and only if holds if you clarify "for all $a,b$".

The first inequality, for fixed $a,b$, implies the second inequality. The second inequality, on the other hand, does not imply the first inequality if you consider it  for fixed $a,b$; you need it to hold for $b,a$.

In summary, the first inequality contains more information.

Comment: Sure, it might contain more information, but why does that matter?  Isn't what is important here the *validity* of the inequalities?

Comment: Can you perhaps give a counter-example?

Comment: Beyond the validity, the inequalities are important because of their usefulness. When you write $|a|-|b|$, maybe its a negative number; saying that the negative number $|a|-|b|$ is less than the positive number $|a-b|$ is not particularly subtle.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I'm not sure I understand; we know that $\forall a, b$ both inequalities hold. Thus for any fixed $a, b$, both inequalities are true, so the biconditional holds. I get that showing  $X \ge |Y| \implies X \ge Y$ is valid regardless of what $X, Y$ stand for, while the converse requires some information about $X$ and $Y$ to determine if it's true or false. But I don't see what this has to do with fixing $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Ovi the point is that even if you didn't know how to prove either inequality, you could deduce that the first one holds for $a,b$ iff the second one holds both for $a,b$ and for $b,a$.

Answer (score 2):

For fun:

$\Rightarrow:$

$|a-b|\ge ||a|-|b|| =$

$\max((|a|-|b|), (|b|-|a|))  \ge $

$|a|-|b|.$

$\Leftarrow:$

1) $|a-b| \ge |a|-|b|;$

Interchange $a$ and $b$:

2) $|b-a| = |a-b| \ge |b| -|a|.$

Hence:

$|a-b| \ge $

$\max((|a|-|b|), (|b| -|a|))=$

$||a|-|b||$.

Answer (score 0):

The RHS is always true by the triangle inequality...  the RHS implies the LHS...
Therefore the LHS is always true...

So they're equivalent...

Answer (score -1):

I think the question that you're **trying** to ask is "how do we use the triangle inequality (which can be rearranged to $|a-b| \geq  |a| - |b|$) to prove the "reverse triangle inequality, namely $|a-b| \geq | |a| - |b| |$.

Here's one way to do it: note that if we exchange the roles of $a$ and $b$ in the first inequality, we find that
$$
|b-a| \geq  |b| - |a|
$$
However, we know that $|b - a| = |-(a - b)| = |a - b|$.  So, the above implies that $|a - b| \geq  |b| - |a|$.  That is, we know that
$$
|a - b| \geq |a| - |b| \quad \text{AND} \quad |a - b| \geq |b| - |a|
$$
To put it more succinctly, we have
$$
|a - b| \geq \max\{|a| - |b|, |b| - |a|\} = \max\{|a| - |b|, -(|a| - |b|)\} = ||a| - |b||
$$
which is the desired result.

Comment: You are proving triangular inequality the OP is asking only for the equivalence which is obvious by symmetry

Comment: @GuyFsone What does "obvious by symmetry" mean here?  The equivalence is "obvious" in the sense that the inequalities always hold.  However, given the comments that OP has made on other answers, the question I have answered is what I think OP is trying to ask.